# Ubuntu 12.10 Fresh Installation - Messed up Graphics

Tags: 12.10, graphics

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 from scratch, and my OS looks like this in lots of places:

[image: Screen capture]

It was already like that during setup, and I have tried reinstalling with no luck.

**Specs**:

- i5 2500k OCed to 4.2 GHZ
- 8 GB RAM
- ASrock P67 Extreme 4 mobo
- GTX 560 TI OC

**Partitions**:

- 550 gb ext4 - This is where I installed Ubuntu
- 200 gb ntfs - Storage
- 170~ gb ntfs - This is for Windows 8, which I haven't installed yet
- 8 GB swap

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: have you installed the nvidia drivers? If not [follow this guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve#NVIDIA_Graphics)

Comment: A windows install will overwrite the bootloader. So you will have to repair the boot process. Once you installed windows your PC will only boot into windows. To repair [follow this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)